# Static library linking error "requires unsupported dynamic reloc"

Tags: gcc, cmake, tensorflow

I built Tensorflow using the scripts provided in `contrib/makefile` of the TF repo. As far as I can tell from the terminal output the generated `libtensorflow-core.a` should have been compiled with `-fPIC` enabled.

Now when I try to link that library into the shared library of an Android NDK project with

```
add_library(lib_tf STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_tf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${TF_BUILD}/libtensorflow-core.a)

add_library(native-lib SHARED ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(native-lib lib_tf)
```

it complains with

```
libtensorflow-core.a(config.pb.o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc R_ARM_REL32; recompile with -fPIC
```

This is the output of `objdump`

```
$ objdump -r libtensorflow-core.a 

libtensorflow-core.a(test_log.pb.o):    file format ELF32-arm-little

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.rel.text]:
0000075c R_ARM_CALL _ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite24WriteMessageMaybeToArrayEiRKNS0_11MessageLiteEPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE
000009b8 R_ARM_CALL _ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10WriteInt64EixPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE
000009cc R_ARM_CALL _ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10WriteInt64EixPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE
00000a1c R_ARM_CALL _ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite16VerifyUtf8StringEPKciNS2_9OperationES4_
00000a34 R_ARM_CALL _ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite11WriteStringEiRKSsPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE
00000a44 R_ARM_REL32 .LC3
...
```

So it seems it was compiled with `-fPIC`. I'm not sure what the problem is.

**UPDATE**:

I compiled it manually via the Android NDK arm toolchain and it worked. I don' know what Android Studio does differently.

Answer (score 0):

my c++ toolchain gave me the same error today when I was trying
to link an object into a shared library for android. The error went away
when I fixed the namespace resolution I was using for an extern variable in the problem source file.

```
namespace {
    namespace android {
        extern int* sys_id ;
    }
}

void home::fileList::report () {
    // do stuff
    initialize (android::sys_id) ;
    // do stuff
}
```

above instigates "requires unsupported dynamic reloc" error, below succeeds

```
namespace m1 {
    namespace android {
        extern int* sys_id ;
    }
}

void home::fileList::report () {
    // do stuff
    initialize (m1::android::sys_id) ;
    // do stuff
}
```